# getUsername is returning null, while CurrentUser is not

Tags: android, parse-platform

So, I'm trying to set up a conditional where it sends the user to the login screen if they aren't logged in, but outputs the username to the log and stays on the current screen if they are logged in.  The problem is that I'm getting a null pointer exception from getUsername being null, but the statement isn't being caught by my `if (getCurrentUser == null)` conditonal.  Where am I going wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

      ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
      if (currentUser == null) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
          intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);
      }

      else {
          Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
        }
  }

      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
    }

      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
          }

          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
      }
```

here's the code i used to create the new user

```
mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mSignupButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        mSignupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
             String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
             String email = mEmail.getText().toString();

                username = username.trim();
                password = password.trim();
                email = email.trim();

                if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);            //warn the user they left some necessary info out
                builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }

                else {
                    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                    newUser.setUsername(username);
                    newUser.setPassword(password);
                    newUser.setEmail(email);
                    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                                startActivity(intent);

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);            //warn the user they left some necessary info out
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: are you use parse database in application?

Comment: where did you initialize Parse

Comment: in the add user page i use 

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

in a file called starterapplication i use


    Parse.initialize(this);

Comment: i know it's initializing because I can see the user I created in my parse dashboard

Comment: do you use  ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser(); where you initialize parse

Comment: yes.  what comes after parse.initialize is

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

Comment: yay it worked.  omg thank you so much!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that you are using  `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();` ,remove this line of code from `onCreate` of

```
your_app extends Application{
}
```

Using `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();`

Anonymous users can also be automatically created for you without requiring a network request, so that you can begin working with your user immediately when your application starts. When you enable automatic anonymous user creation at application startup, `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` will never be `null`. The user will automatically be created in the cloud the first time the user or any object with a relation to the user is saved. Until that point, the user's object ID will be `null`. Enabling automatic user creation makes associating data with your users painless. For example, in your `Application.onCreate()` method, you might write:

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-anonymous-users

Comment: it's still erroring on the line with the Log.i statement :(

Comment: @PaxanaNonGrata : i have edited the answer try it..,if you ccan post logcat also

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: @PaxanaNonGrata: remove ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();refer https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-anonymous-users

Comment: That's so right. I keep on forgetting about this silly thing. Thank you @DeepakJohn

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems what i have done is

```
if ((currentUser == null) && (currentUser.length == 0)) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
```

this worked for me. you can give it a try

Comment: try converting to string and then use length();

Comment: currentUser.toString.length();

Comment: same error on the same line, the line with the log statement

Answer (score 0):

If "getcurrentuser" is of datatype string then you should use ".equals" function of string datatype.like:

String a;

1. if(a.equals(null))
2. if(a.equals("null"))

   one of the above condition will work for you if it still doesn't work then try:

   3. if(a.length==0) : this will give you the length of characters in string "a".